# How do I use std::collections::BitSet in stable Rust?

Tags: rust

I am trying to use `BitSet` data structure, but it gives me a compile error saying it was not able to find the `BitSet.` Has `std::collections::BitSet` been released in the stable version?

```
use std::collections::BitSet;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Produces the error:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `std::collections::BitSet`
 --> src/main.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use std::collections::BitSet;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `BitSet` in `collections`
```

Comment: Please add code example.

Comment: @GregorDoroschenko. Sorry for not doing that earlier. Done now. thanks

Comment: Just curious. You got your answer. So, what documentation or search engine query were you looking or looking at that still referred to the existence of BitSet in stable? It might be helpful to note that for future Rust "SEO" of documentation or of their site.

Comment: @crazysim, Since rust gets a release in every 6 weeks, i thought maybe a newer version than mine, might be having stable API of BitSet.

Comment: My question is what documentation or mention you were referring to that did not mention it's deprecation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that `BitSet` [existed in Rust 1.3.0, which is very old](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.3.0/std/collections/bit_set/struct.BitSet.html), but was already deprecated at that time and finally [removed by this commit](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/7850c8d0aa14cd561fcdce816c94532a3d54ff60).

Instead, you can use [`bit-set` crate](https://crates.io/crates/bit-set), as suggested by the deprecation message above. There's also [documentation](http://contain-rs.github.io/bit-set/bit_set/).

```
extern crate bit_set;

use bit_set::BitSet;

fn main() {
    let mut s = BitSet::new();
    s.insert(32);
    s.insert(37);
    s.insert(3);
    println!("s = {:?}", s);
}
```

You'll have to add a dependency to the `bit-set` crate in some way. It's easy if you're using Cargo:

```toml
[package]
name = "foo"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Foo Bar <foo@example.com>"]

[dependencies]
bit-set = "0.4.0" # Add this line
```

If you're using [the official Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/), you can automatically use `bit-set`, because it is one of [the top 100 downloaded crates](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/the-official-rust-playground-now-has-the-top-100-crates-available/11817) or a dependency of one of them.